# I encountered an error while installing Fabric CA with the go get command

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

when executing

```
go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/
```

I get the following error:

```
go get: installing executables with 'go get' in module mode is deprecated.
Use 'go install pkg@version' instead.   
For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
    or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/internal/pkg/util
/opt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca@v1.5.2/internal/pkg/util/csp.go:117:12: undefined: bccsp.RSA2048KeyGenOpts
/opt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca@v1.5.2/internal/pkg/util/csp.go:119:12: undefined: bccsp.RSA3072KeyGenOpts
/opt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca@v1.5.2/internal/pkg/util/csp.go:121:12: undefined: bccsp.RSA4096KeyGenOpts
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/lib/server/operations
/opt/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca@v1.5.2/lib/server/operations/system.go:173:23: not enough arguments in call to s.statsd.SendLoop
    have (<-chan time.Time, string, string)
    want (context.Context, <-chan time.Time, string, string)
```

go version

go version go1.17.2 linux/amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go 1.17.2 isn't a supported version for fabric-ca 1.5.2 check the release notes for the supported version here https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/releases/tag/v1.5.2

however there is also an issue with a dependency that has changed an api such that using the `-u` option on go get means that it will download and use an incompatible version. This applies only to the server so for the server

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/fabric-ca-server
```

should work, but you can also do

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/...
```

to include a client build as well

You can of course just get official builds from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/releases/tag/v1.5.2

Comment: I reinstalled go1.16.7, the problem is still the same.

Comment: Yep, I see the server part fails. It looks like statsd has been updated but the code base hasn't and gets around this by storing on older version of statsd in the vendor file so it compiles if you get the source from github.

Comment: I cloned the source code from github and it succeeded

Comment: I now try to remove -u to execute the command.

Comment: All were successful, thank you very much for your patient answers.